# SELECT subquery within UPDATE query

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I've never used subqueries before and am having trouble arranging a `SELECT` within an `UPDATE`.

I'm using [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter) here and would like to stick with the *Active Record class* for the sake of consistency if nothing else, but I can work with raw SQL.

Here's my last attempt using the AR class:

```
$this->db->select('locations.id, locations.name');
$this->db->join('locations','location_relationships.id = locations.id');
$sub = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();

$this->db->where('id', $location_id);
$this->db->where('group_id', $team_id);
$query = $this->db->update('location_relationships', $data);
```

Basically, I'm updating a value in this `location_relationships` table, and when that happens want to select some associated cells in the same table and one other (`locations`). So there's also a `JOIN` in the `SELECT` subquery.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This might help you http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Subqueries

Comment: @allen213 close, but it doesn't cover specifically under `UPDATE` queries. I've been reading around through and it may actually be a limitation of MySQL... no `SELECT`s under `UPDATE`s. Odd..

Comment: Write the query in raw sql and make sure it works in your sql client before trying to write it in active record.

Comment: Kindly tell your question more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Put the `UPDATE` first, then do the `SELECT`.

Then you can get rid of the following: `$sub = $this->db->_compile_select(); $this->db->_reset_select();`